# How to install Linux headers without an internet connection?

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, headers

I have a laptop running Kali 2021.3 (amd64 version). It does not have an ethernet port and I need to install the drivers for my network adapter, otherwise I won't be able to access the internet.

I have found a Github repo which contains a community maintained version of the drivers. I have to use dkms to install them.
So, on my other PC, I downloaded dkms using dget on the .dsc you can find under "versioned links" on [this page](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/dkms) . Then, I put it on a pen drive and installed it on my Kali system.

Now dkms apparently needs the linux headers to install the driver.
I have found [this](http://old.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.10.46-4kali1.dsc) which seems to be related to the headers that I need for my version of Kali, used dget to pull it and it gives me two files "linux_5.10.46.orig.tar.xz" and "linux_5.10.46-4kali1.debian.tar.xz".
I'm not sure this archive contains what I am looking for, and if it does, I don't know how to use these archives to install the headers.

Can I install the headers using these files?
If yes, how can I do it?
If not, may you suggest some other way of achieving what I am trying to do?

I can install a different version of Kali if that helps.

Comment: You can download the headers  https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers-on-kali-linux/  ... From there, see if you can install without Internet. I have not tried without Internet.

Comment: Begs the question. Why would you install Kali, designed for network penetration testing, on a system that doesn't have a network port?

Comment: @John that tutorial unfortunately requires an internet connection.

Comment: @doneal24 I want to learn penetration testing using hackthebox.com. I didn't want to install many packages just for that purpose on my main system, so I figured I would install Kali separately, which includes many tools one can use to solve those boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the `.deb` package containing linux-headers for your kernel version (i.e. matching the kernel package). Use `dpkg -i` to offline install that package.

Comment: Yep, looks like I just needed to squint my eyes harder. 
I found the headers [here](http://old.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/) but immediately dismissed it as searching the page for "linux-headers-5.10.46" with CTRL+F led to 0 results.
It seems instead that the headers are compatible with a range of kernel versions, in this case from 5.10.0 to 5.10.46.